# Why doesn't script.js work when I also use plusSlider?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have two scripts the first is `script.js` that uses `quicksand.js` and the second is `plusslider`.

When I use code like the following, the *plusslider* works but the `script.js` doesn't.
But, when I delete the *plussslider* call the `script.js` works fine.

How do I make them work at the same time?

This is my `header.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.plusslider-min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#slider').plusSlider({
    createPagination: false,
    sliderEasing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    fullWidth: true,
    sliderType: 'slider'
    });

});
</script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you remembered the `</script>` tag?

Comment: Maybe they are both using the same namespace/global_var_name and thus one is clobbering the other. Without seeing the code in them its hard to tell. Do you see any errors in the console (using non IE browser)?

Comment: @ NewInTheBusiness yes i did, i just missed it here.

Comment: @ nickdos no ther is'nt any errors :(

Comment: If it's there, edit your post to include `</script>` before `<?php wp_head(); ?>`

Comment: @ RandomDuck.NET already done, same problem continues :(

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't tell if this can be a problem, but try adding an `echo` to `bloginfo('template_url');` to make it: `echo bloginfo('template_url');`.

Comment: If I had to wager a guess I'd say there's quotes that shouldn't be there coming in through the return value of the func. But why not just view source in the browser to see what's going on first?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see how the links appear when you do a view source in the browser. Copy the relevant ones and make sure their addresses load the files in the address-bar.

Also, don't use language="javascript" that was old-school 5 years ago and might throw the right browser with the wrong doctype.

But trust me. Always go to the HTML first, every time. Even if that doesn't help you this time.

Also making sure you're not doing something silly in script.js like overwriting the $ namespace.

Another possible issue. Are all your resource links https? By that I mean images, CSS, other JS files, the actual page you're loading, etc...

Comment: thanks Erik, i've viewed the source everything is fine all scripts are loading well, regarding script.js i tried deleting it and called another script and another and another but it seemed like it will only allow one script at a time to work :(

Comment: Is the html loaded in https? Are all other resources loaded in https? Are you sure you want https in the first place?

Comment: Also, there may be try/catches with empty catch statements in your js files. People should be shot for doing that but they'd probably just keep wiping the blood out of their eyes and continue doing it.